# Entity Framework 6 with Lazy Loading throws ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, lazy-loading, ef-database-first

I am using EF6 with Lazy Loading and database first.

I have this navigations properties in the entity posts:

- Posts.Comments
- Posts.CommentsReference
- Posts.Categories

And this 2 codes:

### Code 1

```
var query = Context.Post.Include(p => p.Categories)
   .ToList()
```

This works fine, and I can navigate to the Categories

### Code 2

```
var query = Context.Posts.Include(p => p.Comments)
   .Join(Context.Users,
   t => t.WritterID,
   h => h.UserID,
   (t, h) => new { Posts= t, Users= h })
   .Where(q => q.Users.Name == "foo user")
   .Select(x => x.Posts)
   .ToList()
```

This throws an **ObjectDisposedException** when I try to navigate to Comments.

Why? Is because the join?

**EDITED**: With code suggestions of @user2674389

Comment: Also it is advised to use expressions as selector in your includes: `.Include(p => p.Comment)`. This way you get a compilation error instead of a runtime error when (out of whatever reason) the Comments navigation property is renamed or removed and you forget to adjust your include.

Comment: @user2674389 the sintaxt does not allaw me to use `.Include(p => p.Comment)`, only `.Include(System.String)`. *May I need a new reference?* About the projection: I don't need the Users data as you can see, so how can I include the Comments in the final projection?.

Comment: For the expression version of `Include` you need to add the `System.Data.Entity` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I switched to LINQ to Entities and it worked fine:

```
var query = from c in Context.Posts.Include(p => p.Comments)
        join h in Context.Users on c.WritterID equals h.UserID
        where h.Users.CompareTo("foo user") == 0
        select c;
```

But I'm still wondering how to do it in lambda expressions...